# Can this open water reservoir be damaged from the ice building inside it?

Tags: water, damage, frost, winter

This circular concrete structure in the garden may have been a well before but now the bottom is closed and a water pipe leads to it. It is roughly a meter deep, 1.3m diameter, 50cm above surface and the walls 12cm thick. It was filled with water and now a thick layer of ice has built on top. An average person can stand on it without it moving.

Could the ice damage the concrete structure? Would it be advisable to remove all water?

Temperatures were as low as -7° Celsius for a day and are unlikely to go much lower than that before March brings much warmer weather.

[image]

Comment: How much of the structure is above ground?  What are the expected minimum temperatures and how long do they last?  We get up to -40 deg Celsius for a few days every few years and my plastic rain barrel which is entirely underground does not crack. It all depends...

Comment: I added some more info. It is unlikely that temperatures would go below -10°C

Comment: @djangonaut Did the basin crack?  How did it turn out?

Comment: @MackM no cracks or damages. It survived all winters since as well.